# javascript error in nifi executeScript

Tags: javascript, apache-nifi

I am having an issue getting the javascript script for the executeScript nifi process to work and would appreciate help with this. The goal is to pass a flowfile which will contain a json object. I need to parse this json without knowing the content/fields prior and pass this along to write it out to the flowfile that is being passed out to the next process that is MergeContent and counts the number flowfiles.
Tried testing the script and got the following error:

```
 nifi.script.ExecuteScript - ExecuteScript[id=bd6842e9-e3a4-4d88-a59d- 
 7da1d74d109b] ExecuteScript[id=bd6842e9-e3a4-4d88-a59d-7da1d74d109b] 
 failed to process due to 
 org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: 
 javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:21:17 Expected : but found value
         let value = json[key];
             ^ in <eval> at line number 21 at column number 17; rolling 
 back session: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: 
 javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:21:17 Expected : but found value
```

I am not very familiar with javascript so would appreciate the help.

```
flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile != null) {

var StreamCallback = 
Java.type("org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback");
var IOUtils = Java.type("org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils");
var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");
var transformed_message = {};
var error = false;
var line = "ops_testQueue";

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new StreamCallback(function 
  (inputStream, outputStream) {

    var content = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, 
  StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // message or content
    var message_content = {};
    try {
        message_content = JSON.parse(content);
        if(Array.isArray(message_content)){

    }
    Object.keys(message_content).forEach((key) => {
         var value = json[key];
         result.push(key + '=' + value);
         var jkey = "," +  "\"" + key + "\""  + '=' + value   
        });
    line = line + jkey +
            " value=" + "1"
            + " " + Date.now() * 1000000;


        // Write output content
        if (transformed_message) {
            outputStream.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
    } catch (e) {
        error = true;
        outputStream.write(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
 }));
 if (transformed_message.post_state) {
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "type", 
    transformed_message.type);
}

if (error) {
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
} else {
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
}
```

}

EDIT:

input to executeScript:

```
 {"pID":"1029409411108724738",
  "contentType":"text",
  "published":"2018-08-14 16:48:23Z",
  "crawled":"2018-08-14 12:48:33-04:00",
  "ID":"765"}
```

output from executeScript:

```
ops_testQueue,"ID"=765 value=1 1534265314969999870
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw a couple of things here:

1. I don't know if Nashorn (Java's JS Engine) supports the full lambda
   syntax, I was able to get it to work by making the lambda a function
   (see script below).
2. You refer to a `json` variable to get the value from a key, but I think you want `message_content`.
3. `result` is not defined, so you get an error when you push to it.

Here's an edited version of your script that I got to work the way I think you want it (but please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile != null) {

var StreamCallback = 
Java.type("org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback");
var IOUtils = Java.type("org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils");
var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");
var transformed_message = {};
var error = false;
var line = "ops_testQueue";

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new StreamCallback(function 
  (inputStream, outputStream) {

    var content = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, 
  StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // message or content
    var message_content = {};
    try {
        message_content = JSON.parse(content);
        if(Array.isArray(message_content)){

    }
    var jkey = "";
    Object.keys(message_content).forEach(function(key) {
         var value = message_content[key];
         //result.push(key + '=' + value);
         jkey = "," +  "\"" + key + "\""  + '=' + value   
        });
    line = line + jkey +
            " value=" + "1"
            + " " + Date.now() * 1000000;

        // Write output content
        if (transformed_message) {
            outputStream.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
    } catch (e) {
        error = true;
        log.error(e);
        outputStream.write(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
 }));
 if (transformed_message.post_state) {
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "type", 
    transformed_message.type);
}

if (error) {
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
} else {
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
}
}
```

Comment: @Mattyb...you are a lifesaver. Thank you so much for catching those errors and your suggested changes. Really appreciate it. The script worked with your tester. Just need to apply it to the flowfile processes and see if everything ends up in Influx. Would it be possible to ping you if I have any other questions?

Comment: Sure! You can also subscribe to the dev and/or users mailing lists for NiFi, that way other folks can help with answers/advice as well :)

Comment: Not sure if I should start a new question; but the output of the script above is not including all the json fields, only one field, the value= and the date. I will edit the post to include a sample json message.

Comment: Your `jkey` variable keeps getting overwritten, the line that adds key/values to it should start with `jkey = jkey + ...`